# Virtual address vs Physical address

Tags: operating-system

I understand that physical address space depends on RAM. If we have 1GB ram, the physical address space size is 1GB. Whereas every process has its own virtual address space, e.g. a 32 bit machine has 4GB virtual address space for each process.

If we write something to a physical address space in a baremetal application, let us take write 1234 in address 0x1000, so the data will be written in to 0x1000th offset of 1GB of physical address space.

My doubt is, in virtual address space process-1 wants to write 0x1234 at 0x1000 offset, the same way process-2 wants the same data at the same offset. How it will work?

I want to understand how the multiple virtual address spaces are mapped to a single physical address space.

2.
I understand your point, if physical adress contains 40 bits, then only it can map Ram,Rom and others I/O's.

Where can we refer width( bits) of physical address space and virtual address space?

Is baremetal or microcontroller code access directly physical address space? Also it does not have multitasking and multithreading feature?

Comment: This isn't a software development question, so I don't believe Stack Overflow is the correct home for it. I could suggest either [su] or more likely [cs.se] would be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

> Till now what I understand is physical address space depends on Ram. If we have 1gb ram, physical address space size is 1gb.

For the physical address space; some physical addresses correspond to RAM, some are other things (ROM, devices), and a lot are literally nothing (unused). If you have 1 GiB of RAM, then physical addresses may be 40 bits and physical address space size may be 1024 GiB (where 1 GiB of it might be RAM, 128 MiB might be ROM and devices, and over 1022 GiB is literally nothing).

> My doubt is in virtual address space process-1 wants to 0x1234 at 0x1000 offset, same way process-2 wants same data in same offset. How it will work?

The CPU uses a set of tables (called "page tables") to convert virtual addresses into physical addresses. Typically each process has its own set of page tables, and when the OS does a task switch from one process to another it also switches from the previous process' page tables to the next process' page tables.

If process 1 writes 0x1234 at virtual address 0x1000 in its virtual address space then (using process 1's page tables) the CPU might write the value 0x1234 at physical address 0x1111000. If process 2 writes 0x4567 at virtual address 0x1000 in its virtual address space then (using process 2's page tables) the CPU might write the value 0x4567 at physical address 0x2222000. Because the virtual address spaces are different (because the processes have their own page tables) the physical addresses are different, so there's no problem (physical address 0x1111000 has nothing to do with physical address 0x22220000).